# Estoy empezando con PySpark y tengo un problema que no entiendo

Tags: java, python-3.x, cmd, pyspark, spark

Estoy tratando de ejecutar este codigo

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Read File')
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

rdd = sc.textFile('data1.txt')
print(rdd.collect())

#rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(' '))
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: x+' Pablo')
print(rdd2.collect())
```

Pero al llegar al rdd2.collect() aparece un error que no se como solucionar, por algunos lados recomendaban desinstalar y reinstalar, cambiar variables de entorno, utilizar diferentes versiones de python/java, lo he probado todo y sigue sin funcionar, no entiendo cual es el problema.

Captura del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las versiones que tengo instaladas:

Python: 3.12.1
Java: 11.0.20
Spark: 3.5.0
Hadoop: 3.3.6

Y las variables de entorno las tengo todas puestas, JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME, SCALA_HOME y en path igual pero a las carpetas \bin

Saludos y gracias.